# polymer app with phonegap showing blank screen

Tags: android, html, cordova, polymer

I am testing polymer with phonegap.When I try this with the phonegap app,it is working but when i build it with adobe build and try it with my device it is showing a blank screen.
This is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="bower_components/paper/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">

    </script>
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="import"
  href="bower_components/paper/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import"
  href="bower_components/paper/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import"
  href="bower_components/paper/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import"
  href="bower_components/paper/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
    <link rel="import"
  href="bower_components/paper/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
        <link rel="import"
  href="bower_components/paper/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
 <style>
html,body{
    height : 100%;
    margin : 0;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    font-family : 'RobotoDraft' , 'sans-serif';
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color : rgba(0,0,0,0);
}    
core-toolbar {
    background-color:#4285f4;
    color : white;

}
.dropdown{

    color : black;

}
</style>  
    <script>
              app.initialize();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<core-toolbar>

    <paper-icon-button icon = "menu">

    </paper-icon-button>

    <span flex>Hello world</span>
   <paper-menu-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon = "create"></paper-icon-button>
       <paper-dropdown class = "dropdown" halign = "right">
           <paper-menu>
               <paper-item><div id = "hi">hi</div></paper-item>
           </paper-menu>
       </paper-dropdown>
    </paper-menu-button>

    </core-toolbar>
   <paper-button>Test</paper-button> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have made other apps but not with polymer that work with phonegap.
I am running android 5.0.2.
Thanks.

Comment: I dont see `cordova.js`

Comment: I forgot to add it! I added that but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling hardware acceleration is an (ugly) workaround.